# Getting unable to attach file error while attaching file in Gmail

Tags: android, android-fileprovider

I am trying to attach a pdf file from Downloads folder of internal storage to Gmail app using Intent. But it gives me error of `Unable to attach the file`. I am using FileProvider for getting the file of downloads folder. Here is the code that I have written.

**MainActivity**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    File pdfDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Download");
    File pdfFile = new File(pdfDirectory, "fileName.pdf");
    Uri pdfFileContentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, APPLICATION_ID + ".fileprovider", pdfFile);

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("application/pdf");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, pdfFileContentUri);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

**AndroidManifests**

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
    </provider>
</application>
```

**provider_paths**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
</paths>
```

Can somebody guide how to solve this issue?

Comment: Try to open the file yourself. After `Uri pdfFileContentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, APPLICATION_ID + ".fileprovider", pdfFile);` open an InputStream like `InputStream is = getContentResolver().openInputStrem(pdfFileContentUri);`. Does it open?

Comment: Before trying to get an uri you could add `if(!pdfFile.exists()){Toast(file does not exist...); return;}`

Comment: On wich Android version are you ?

Comment: I tried opening the input stream. It did not give any exception

Comment: My targetSdkVersion is 28 and I am debugging in my mobile device has android oreo 8.1.0

Comment: You have no EXTRA_SUBJECT or EXTRA_TEXT. Try if that would help. Try a different email app too. You could install another. Try adding other files.

Comment: What is the size of PDF file ?

Comment: also.. tried the toast as you suggested. But it is not getting invoked. So the file exists

Comment: the size of pdf file is just 347.04 kb

Comment: Examine Logcat and see if Gmail is logging anything that will give you more clues. Note that you need `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` to use that filesystem location (including runtime permissions), and that you have no access to that location on Android 10 (by default) and beyond (for all apps).

Comment: @CommonsWare, it would be interesting if the input stream could be opened (see my first comment) without the read permission. If it can be opened without the permission then some reads had to be done too to be sure.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thank you for your help. It worked after giving the permission to read the external storage